# Python package install using pip to source doesn't create a symlink

Tags: virtualenv, pip

So I'm a convert with pip and virtualenv.  One of the things I've found is that when I use a requirements.txt with contents which look like this the subsequent `pip -E -r requirements.txt` works as intended..

```
PIL==1.1.7
chardet==1.0.1
distribute==0.6.14
django-extensions==0.6
django-profiles==0.2
```

But when you start getting fancy with your requirements.txt by pulling source trees, the following behavior is seen.  1) It pull the source into "source" tree. (That's good)  2) It fails to create a symlink to this in the site-packages tree but rather create *.link (.ie django-debug-toolbar.egg-link )

```
-e git+https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar.git@9067568b0bbf0c39322f5b761b05463685355b4f#egg=django_
debug_toolbar-dev
-e hg+https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration@fad7080fe76955e7d0d3c97bc468ea8360260a6b#egg=django_registration
-dev
-e git://github.com/yourcelf/django-registration-defaults.git@df80e13fd5f4ee3c96d4508fa12278c47c660c37#egg=django_registrati
on_defaults-dev
```

The problem is that now I have to create the symlink to the source tree from the site-packages tree.
To fix this I shift over to the site-packages tree and start creating symlinks back to the sources tree.

**I'm sure there is a better way to do this - can someone please enlighten me??**

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, have you figured out what the issue is?

Comment: Opened pip bug on this issue: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/435

Comment: You probably want to stop using `pip -E`; it is inherently broken, particularly with --no-site-packages virtualenvs (which is now the default in virtualenv 1.7). It is already removed in the development version of pip and will be gone in the next release. Instead, just use the copy of pip that is automatically installed inside every virtualenv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to create a symlink at all, the so called `*.egg-link` files in the site-packages directory of the virtualenv will act as a symlink on Python (well, actually setuptools) level.

EDIT: I added a bit of background info here: http://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/435

Comment: Do you know how that works?  Is that an idiom of setuptools?  Nevermind - your answer here (github.com/pypa/pip/issues/435) provided all the necessary links!  Awesome

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: If the issue is that you're editor/LSP-server can't find packages installed as editable, then try:

```
SETUPTOOLS_ENABLE_FEATURES=legacy-editable pip install -e .
```

> The problem is that now I have to create the symlink to the source
> tree from the site-packages tree.
>
> -- rh0dium

> You don't have to create a symlink at all, the so called *.egg-link
> files in the site-packages directory of the virtualenv will act as a
> symlink on Python (well, actually setuptools) level.
>
> -- jezdez

It wasn't clear from the original post what problem rh0dium was encountering.

jezdez is correct that Python's import system doesn't require you to create a symlink.

So, who cares if you don't have a symlink?

Well, I found this message while trying to troubleshoot why my LSP server couldn't find a package if I installed it with `pip install -e .`.

I found just a small number of GitHub issues and StackOverflow posts mentioning the issue, and in those I occasionally saw a suggestion to run `SETUPTOOLS_ENABLE_FEATURES=legacy-editable pip install -e .`. That solved my problem. My IDE now reports that it can find the dependencies whereas before it couldn't. There's still not a symlink in `site-packages`. But the `.dist-info` folder changed to a `.egg-link` file.

I don't understand what goes on behind the scenes to make this work. If someone does, please leave a comment.